# Is there a "SD Memory Card Formatter" equivalent for Linux?

Tags: sd-card

I routinely need to completely erase SD cards.

This process is greatly speed up using [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/).

Unfortunately said program seems to be unavailable under Linux and alternatives (e.g.: `dd` or `shred`) take a LOOOONG time.

AFAIK SD/MMC cards have specific commands to mass-erase and I suspect that's what used by "SD Memory Card Formatter" (as opposed to trying to erase using their content by overwriting).

Is there some tool using the same?

Comment: Do you care about security as in "data should not be recoverable"?

Comment: `dd` can be fast if you find the right blocksize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use blkdiscard

In short:

```
blkdiscard /dev/mmcblk0
```

### Discussion

To quickly erase an entire SD card, you can use the `blkdiscard`[(8)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkdiscard.8.html) command. This calls the Linux BLKDISCARD ioctl, which in turn passes CMD38, the same as [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/).

### Interesting options

- `-s`, `--secure` securely discard blocks. As has been pointed out elsewhere, a normal CMD38 will make some blocks appear empty, but leave others plainly visible due to garbage collection. Use `-s` if you wish to be a little more secure and force garbage collected blocks to also be erased.
- `-z`, `--zero` zero-fill blocks rather than discard.

### Does not work over USB

Note that while this works on my laptop and Raspberry Pi, it would not work on a USB SD card reader. The difference is that kernel needs to have access to the low-level [MMC](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/mmc/index.html) subsystem, which USB abstracts away as a generic "mass storage" device. [I believe Microsoft Windows has the same limitation, but please correct me in the comments if I'm wrong.]

If you do not have a device that can speak directly to the low-level SD card, it is possible to build one out of an Arduino and run [SDFormatter.ino](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/examples/SdFormatter/SdFormatter.ino).

### Extraordinarily dangerous!

Since `blkdiscard` must be run as root, it can easily **destroy** all of your data. You better be sure that you are pointing it at the right device and then double-check again. Use `lsblk` and `df`.

The manpage claims that, to be safe, it will only work if the drive isn't already mounted. That would be a nice safety feature, but it is not true as of this writing. The current implementation requires the `-f`, `--force` option if the drive is already formatted, which is (almost) always going to be the case since SD cards come pre-formatted. Unfortunately, using `--force` means that *all* checks, including if the drive is in use, are disabled.

Hopefully someday Linux will allow blkdiscard to be run on removable devices without requiring root privileges which would make it much less dangerous.

### Other uses

Besides quickly wiping out data for privacy, supposedly blkdiscard, similar to fstrim for an SSD, will improve wear-leveling and make some SD cards [generally run a little bit faster](https://gitlab.com/scalvin/stickpic).

Comment: For SSDs, is there a difference between ```blkdiscard``` and ```hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass password /dev/sdX; hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced password /dev/sdX```?

Comment: I don't know if hdparm uses **BLKSECDISCARD** for security erase on SSDs, but I suspect not since that is an [ATA command](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase). Of course internally in the drive it may be implemented as the same thing, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4):

Since recently SD Memory Card Formatter (CLI version) is **available for Linux** (for x86_64 and arm64):
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/sd-memory-card-formatter-for-linux/

I needed to use the official SD Memory Card Formatter some time ago, preferably under Linux (as part of a toolchain), so I emailed the SD Association about it. They are very responsive and helpful. And recently they emailed me back with the information that the formatter is now available for Linux.

Comment: Thanks for being the squeaky wheel that prompted them to release a tool! And thanks for taking the time to share their response with StackExchange. If you're up for it, I have a few suggestions for how you might make the answer even better. For example: How does SD Memory Card Formatter differ from LInux's `blkdiscard`? Is it under an open license? Also, you only mention x86_64 and arm64. If it doesn't work on arm32, you might want to mention that since most Raspberry Pis currently run in 32-bit mode even when they have 64-bit processors.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make the point of the reporter:
https://forum.armbian.com/topic/3776-the-partition-is-not-resized-to-full-sd-card-size/?do=findComment&comment=27413

> tkaiser
>
> Posted March 13, 2017
>
> Regarding 'reserve sectors' and overprovisioning: If a card claims it's n bytes in capacity it has internally a larger capacity. This is used as reserve (if the controller detects bad sectors, then reserve sectors are mapped in) and to allow somewhat ok-ish write performance when the card gets full. On flash media you can't overwrite directly, it's always a very time consuming read/delete/write cycle, the number a flash cell can be written to is determined by the count of program/erase (P/E) cycles it is designed for, the controller has to take care of this so that all flash cells wear out equally (wear leveling).
>
> Since the controller has no idea which sectors contain real data and which not ([there's no TRIM support for SD cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)#SD.2FMMC)) as soon as you completely fill the card once (all space partitioned) from now on the controller considers every sector containing useful data (even if you deleted the data in the meantime -- since there's no TRIM support the controller doesn't know what's empty or not, from now on the whole capacity is considered in use). Now only the 'reserve sectors' are available to perform read/delete/write cycles and if this amount of sectors is small things slow down a lot on average SD cards (not those more recent Samsung).
>
> Just check articles explaining SSDs and keep in mind that SD cards behave like crappy SSDs from a decade ago containing slow/primitive controllers and do not support TRIM.
>
> BTW: This is the only great use case for SD Association's 'SD Formatter'. This tool is used to format SD cards appropriately (partitions it while choosing the 'correct' file system which is either FAT or exFAT) which obviously is pretty useless from Armbian's perspective since burning an OS image as next step both overwrites the partition table and the filesystems present before. So why using SD Formatter in the first place? Since this tool implements ERASE CMD38. It tells the card's controller that every sector/block of the card does not contain any real data any more and can be considered empty. On 'the average' SD card this also might restore horribly low performance back to 'factory default' performance. But more recent SD card controllers especially when paired with many reserve sectors aren't that much affected.
>
> (...)
>
> **Edit**: A small note regarding 'SD cards don't support TRIM'. The SD protocol defines a block erase command and tools like fstrim are supposed to do the job. Whether your kernel + SD card combination supports that or not a simple 'sudo fstrim -v /' might tell. Whether this has the desired effect or not is a different question though (see this attempt to test this -- I'm not sure whether the method is sufficient since the point of marking data segments as already erased should not involve overwriting them, it's just that the SD card's controller knows that specific sectors/pages can be added to the wear level pool since marked 'emtpy' now)

So there is no Linux equivalent to sdcard.org SD Formatter which is only available for windows and mac.

And fstrim or dd are not replacements. I do not know why we miss such a tool. Likely with improved overprovisioning and better controllers this will not be a huge problem in the long term. Maybe ask Tuxera which made SD Formatter if they plan for an Android or plain linux version.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `dd` correctly it's extremely fast:

There is no reason to overwrite the whole card, that will always take a long time, no matter what software you use. You just have to remove the first sectors (partition table):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/locationofcard bs=1024 count=1000
```

A way lower count will also do the job, but this should already be fast enough (seconds).

I am using 1000 as 'safe' value because i don't know by heart how low you can get.

Comment: No. I need to be sure the WHOLE card is zero-filled.

Comment: In that case there is nothing faster then `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/locationofcard` (without options), if there is software that looks faster then it's because it is skipping parts. But why would you need to zero-fill the whole card ? (The only thing i can think of is security and in that case you should do multiple overwrites with random data instead of 1 overwrite with zero's)

Comment: I beg to differ. SDcards are "intelligent" devices and many have "erase yourself" (or, to be more precise, "discard all sectors") commands that work essentially in parallel on all sectors at once. I would even know how to do it, but that would mean to go to DD level, which I would rather avoid, if possible. Reason why I need this erasure is we use SD for special purpose and software will "manage" all non-zero sectors, even if they do not contain meaningful  data, do "empty" cards should be all zeroed (strange things happen in the embedded world ;) )

Comment: @Garo: "nothing faster than `dd` without options"? By default it uses a tiny block size of only 512 bytes. That's _extremely_ slow for most if not all media, in particular SD Cards. Nowadays one should always use at least 4K as a bare minimum, preferably 1M.

Comment: If the partition table is GPT, there's a second one at the end of the block device.

Answer (score 1):

SD cards do not need to be formatted. "Formatting" is an old term specific for magnetic disks, where you prepare the tracks and sectors for actual data (they are not defined by disk, but by the head when you format the disk. So formatting is very slow.

Now "formatting" is not more such slow process, so it is not really formatting.

Often programs will just do a `mkfs` style *formatting*, so just creating the structure of file systems. Where to put data is already defined by card and internal controller.

Unfortunately I'm not find the command (given by controller) just to tell disk that sectors are not used. This may help, but possibly it is part of `mkfs` (hidden on kernel side). But do not do unnecessarily `dd` but on real magnetic harddisk: on SD, SSD, etc. they just consume the device.

Comment: Again: I am aware of how the whole system works. I need to be SURE the WHOLE card is zero-filled, even "not used" sectors.

Comment: The "great" speed it seems that they use exactly the same trick.They told the card to DISCARD sectors. so you will read them as zero. But the sectors may be restored in appropriate facilities. BTW also if you write zero the usual facilities to restore data can get most of original data. [so: never gives other people cards where you put confidential information]

Comment: That is ok with me. I do not need it for security reasons, but because some tools (i have no way to change) will process "all non zero sectors", regardless of they being actually linked in a filesystem. So I don't care if content could be restored "in appropriate facilities", it's enough that raw read return zeroed sectors. Do You have news of such a tool running on Linux? ... and, if you can, could you tell me where You gleamed info about that closed tool?

Comment: It is not a closed tool. It is in protocol. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive has a lot of information. Many SD cards are similar (especially the newest/fast ones)

Comment: Uhm... I wouldn't be so sure. Their EULA states clearly You are not supposed to try to reverse engineer from binary to source. Thanks for the pointer! ... but it seems to deal with SSD (Solid State Disk), which is a bit different from SD (Secure Digital)

Comment: It is not reverse engineer. We are not looking the internal of a card. It is just the standard protocol used to talk with the cards. It is standard (with many extensions). Write here, trim data, fetch data, get capabilities, etc: card must works on many systems, so there is a standard. As I wrote, modern SD are similar to old SSD, but look: I found something interesting for you: https://superuser.com/questions/18906/can-i-use-something-like-the-ssd-trim-command-on-a-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

A note about SD standard compliance: "SD Specifications Part 2: File System Specification" v3.00 ("SD.2"; try Google or libgen) has special restrictions on the SD card partitioning and formatting structure. The official formatter will obey it, but you might not. Some important points are:

- The standard is MBR, one partition of type "F8" only. There is *no* telling what happens if you use anything else. The worst-case scenario is a [Samsung SSD-like GPT corruption issue](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/ssds-are-incompatible-with-gpt-partitioning.2228064/). Best-case? Some speed reduction for the second partition's FAT.
- The standard *wants* (Informative Appendix C; "should" elsewhere) you to position the partition to align the FAT area with a number of Boundary Units (~physical page), so that this special page can be optimized for frequent small I/O but also doesn't get filled by files.

  - For FAT12/16/32, you need to partition correctly since there's no FAT offset mechanism. For 12/16, SD.2 wants you to squeeze the FATs into the first BU with with the MBR and everything. For 32, SD.2 wants you to put the partition start at the beginning of the second BU.

    `mkfs.fat` has no knowledge of a BU. It does align to cluster (~fs block) size, which makes sense for FAT32 but not necessarily the smaller formats. Manual alignment is possible with reserve sectors, but very tedious.
  - For ExFAT, you technically have the same requirement at BU, but the filesystem itself lets you shift the FAT around, so getting it wrong is less severe of an issue.

    [`mkfs.exfat`](https://manned.org/mkfs.exfat) reads the position of the partition relative to disk start *and* makes use of this information to [calculate a good offset](https://github.com/exfatprogs/exfatprogs/blob/8593314715f4c0e531ee7cb26bdd4cd06e8a3f7f/mkfs/mkfs.c#L452-L453).

The easiest to format in a standard-recommended way is ExFAT, because the formatting tool is smart enough: if you get the BU size and cluster size right (the default differs from SD.2 recommendation, but you can read [its manpage](https://manned.org/mkfs.exfat) for SD.2 recs), you are on the right path. Partition to BU offset for pedantry, or don't, because it won't matter too much anyways.

As for the legacy FAT formats, good luck: you will need to calculate the FAT size and then translate that into either the reserve sector count (FAT32) or the partition offset (FAT12/16). This could be a feature request to the dosfstools/fatprogs people, with very dubious usefulness.